# To create an eclipse project from just the folders

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I work in an organisation where i am provided with a folder having codes and other things for particular application.
I want to open this folder in eclipse and be able to navigate to all the classes that are used through resources(ctrl + click).
The problem is when I imported the folder the eclipse worked same as that of a notepad. Any changes no error would be shown.
I even added the required jar files for that project.
What should I do? I just need to navigate and check out the classes that are used and declared. Pls Help.

P.S. - I work on Ubuntu Machine.

Comment: Have you tried creating a "Java project"?

Comment: Yes, create a Java project and copy the java sources to the src/ folder.

Comment: yeah.. thnx. It worked. I was actually adding a folder which in turn had a folder which had source files..

Answer (score 0):

If you have a java project, you may need to configure the source directory(s).

This can be done by right clicking on your folder -> Build Path -> Use as Source Folder.